# What is in your opinion the best structure for react-projects?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am creating a website with vite. Right now, I have a src folder and in that folder I have an app.tsx. In the router section I have it linking to my navbar and the pages. Inside the pages I linked it to the different parts of my page. So I create my structure per part of the website. Because of this I have a lot of files. What do you think is the best structure and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to structure a React project. One of the best ways to organize your React components is to group them by feature. This means that all the components related to a specific feature of your application are grouped together in a single folder. Another alternative is to group components by file type. You can also separate components into folders by role. It’s important to avoid having too deep of a folder structure2. Don’t worry too much about the details at first, you can always refactor later.
Here is an example of an ideal folder structure for a large-scale React app that resembles a social media platform like Facebook:

```
src/
  actions/
  reducers/
  components/
  styles/
  utils/
  views/
  App.js
  index.js
  package.json
  README.md
```